# Recreate existing logo in different format

Tags: logo, client-relations

I have been asked by a client to recreate their logo in a new file type. The client owns the logo, but the brand book they bought is from another designer.  Can I legally recreate the client's logo for them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if they paid the previous designer they should own the work previously delivered and the right to use it in any way they need to. That includes passing the work to another designer to provide additional service based on their existing items.